# Precision of Java math functions

Tags: java

I was coding some floating point intensive algorithm and couldn't get the outcomes as expected (actually I am trying to migrate my old C program into Java). Still a newbie in Java, 2 months old! ;) So I made some quick test on math function and found this:

```
System.out.printf("Math.PI^1 = %.22f MAth.PI^10 = %.22f \n", 
    Math.pow(Math.PI, 1.0), Math.pow(Math.PI, 10.0));
```

And the output is as follow:

```
Math.PI^1 = 3.1415926535897930000000 MAth.PI^10 = 93648.0474760829800000000000
```

As a reference, the Calculator gives pi^10 as follow:

```
93,648.047476083020973716690184919
```

, which is what I expected to get. Minor error is Ok, as the output from C math function (Cygwin environment) gives as follow:

```
printf("M_PI^1 = %.22f M_PI^10 = %.22f \n", pow(M_PI,1.0), pow(M_PI, 10.0));

$ ./a.exe
M_PI^1 = 3.1415926535897931159980 M_PI^10 = 93648.0474760829820297658443
```

Have I missed something critical? Or any Java configuration I didn't specify? Yes, I've searched and found about StrictMath and strictfp keyword to use. But still they give the same outcome in Java.

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` if you want precision in `Java`...`float` and `double` are prone to rounding errors.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: And do **not** use `BigDecimal` if you want reasonable performance. As Jose Antonio Dura Olmos pointed out in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32205025/3182664), both results are **the same**, just printed differently.

Comment: @brso05 This is not specific for Java: float and double act according to IEEE, with an optional `strictfp`, and the precision of the Math functions is usually documented in terms of ulps.

Comment: @Marco13 i never said it was specific to Java...

Answer (score 7):

float has about 7.2 significative decimal digits.
double has about 15.9 significative decimal digits.

Your examples have the same 16 first significative decimal digits. This means that both pieces of code are getting **exactly the same binary result**. Assuming that your C compiler uses the same IEEE standard for 64 bit floats as java which is likely.

The difference you see after those 16 digits does not come from the way the math operation is performed and does not come from rounding error but from the way the different print functions deal with converting from binary double to decimal text.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way to get a correct answer is to use [Wolfram alpha pi^10](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%5E10) this give the value of 93648.04747608302097371669018491934563599815727551469412705244 more digits could probably be obtained if needed. We see the cygwin C code is only correct to 15 digits

```
93648.0474760829820297658443   C 
93648.04747608298              Java
93648.04747608302097371669018491934563599815727551469412705244
93648.047476082984468098606014523496270846023460034084392213341627
```

so you have exactly the same precision in both systems. You would expect to get same precision as both will likely use the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) double precision floating point. You could say that java answer is better as it is not giving a false sense of accuracy by displaying more digits.

Unless you are specifically interested in calculating digits of pi or other number theory related task 16 digit accuracy will satisfy your needs. I've never seen an application where BigDecimal has proved to be useful and it requires a lot of work to get right.

A BigDecimal solution would be

```
    MathContext mc = MathContext.DECIMAL128;
    BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal("3.141592653589793238462643383279503",mc);
    BigDecimal res = pi.pow(10, mc);
    out.println(pi);
    out.println(res);
```

This uses a specific MathContext, the most accurate pre-defined one. If the numbers are approximate, as pi is, then its better to specify a MathContext. The only time you really want to use BigDecimal without a MathContext is if your values are exact, I not come across a time when you want to use this.

We use the string constructor with a value obtained from Wolfram alpha and the MathContext to fix the precision. We also use the same MathContext when calculating the power. The result of this is

```
3.141592653589793238462643383279503
93648.04747608302097371669018491938
```

if we compare this with the actual result which ends in 934 we see the result has an error in the last digit. Generally you expect most mathematics algorithms to be correct to within one unit of the last place, pow is a bit worse with a 2 ulp error. Using a MathContext mean we do not display spurious incorrect digits.

Comment: yes, I did compare those results in C n Java. BigDecimal is way so fantastic! But like u said, its practical use might be an issue. My code algo requires lots of trigono formula. Error in, say, 5th decimal place, would result much greater error at final outcome. Error at the 13th or beyond decimal places would be ok. However, I would still rely on that 'double' data type. Why not? It's supposed to be IEEE754 64-bit compliant. Another way for me to try is to readjust the formula in the code, eg breaking long expressions into chunks. I've encountered problem like this before & solved it

Comment: Yes I would go with double apart from a very small subset of specialised application. The need for trig pretty much rules BigDecimal out as these are not supported by default and you would need to reimplement all the algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. Java and C both suck at floating point numbers. You should really use floating point for estimates and not exact values. Anything above currency and you're going to have some inconsistencies.

If you want precision, you will need to use BigDecimal. You'll want to test it for performance, but you should get the answers you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigDecimal` class if you want precision. `float`'s and `double`'s are prone to rounding errors:

```
BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal(Math.PI);
System.out.println(test.pow(10));
```

Output:

```
93648.047476082984468098606014523496270846023460034084392213341627785026090824331731984972528115769903975226563675097646096540840763090025329795404848362261074645725271801449534201154156882626448229305882846309041714031912085482167747513529870413304782789850546982088436194217303991296601721838481502870491848946572115751298158673535944440534837506339231012720875785869801057751354819447705578284437850332884027121079143234804533501909778030213894750577452441575587727129459381103515625
```

Comment: "That is likely to be an incorrect value." Why don't you figure it out for sure before commenting. Let the OP decide you don't need to decide for him.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the correct answer should atleast say why.

Comment: @Salixalba read the OP's question `"Minor error is Ok"` the precision comes into play when doing `BigDecimal.pow()` the input is close enough that when `BigDecimal.pow()` is called the result is close enough to what it should be.

Comment: @Salixalba the precision for PI is not the problem it is fine if PI is a `double` it is when you do PI ^ 10 you have the precision problem if you convert PI to `BigDecimal` first then do your `pow(10)` it should be fine for what the OP wants remember to **fully** read the question **"Minor error is Ok"**. You really should let the OP decide what is right. Don't just downvote for no reason.

Comment: Who else downvoted the correct answer. You shouldn't downvote correct answers!

Comment: Thanks guys... Actually my ori C code works fine. Migrating to Java, I was a bit surprised when outcome differs. Java is cool :) So I put simple debug printf() those intermediate variables; it shows they tend to drift. I use 'double', and in principle it should be fine. IEEE754 64-bit Std is more than enough. So last night I compared the result:

`   C float :        93648.070312500000000000000000000000000000
C double:        93648.047476082982029765844345092773437500
Java double:     93648.04747608298
Java float:      93648.07
Java BigDecimal: .perfect!`
I don't think it's just printf issue.

Comment: Pardon my reply text formatting above. I did try pre and code tag format but it doesn't work

Comment: @LaminaR.Schwank if this answer solved your problem please mark it as correct.

Comment: @ brso05 . My problem is not solved yet... am still debugging it, zooming into details, into intermediate variables. FYI i'm using     <pre> <code> javac 1.8.0_51 </code> </pre> version.

Comment: @LaminaR.Schwank if you want in-line code use `` `test`.

Answer (score 1):

You see those roundings because `double` type is implemented in java ([JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)) according to [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Which in turn:

> gives 15–17 significant decimal digits precision

So the precision you see comes from the standard. As it was suggested in other answers you could consider using `BigDecimal` for a higher precision.